# Prevent login with one user in different browser .NET Core

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, .net-5

I want to create a login page that contain user and password with ASP.NET Core 5.

How can I prevent login with one user in different browser?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest at login you create a unique token that is stored on the server and passed back to the client as either an encrypted cookie value or if you are using Claims authentication as a claim.  You then write a filter to test that the sent token matches the server side stored value on Authentication.  You may want to store and update a datetime on the token - similar to a sliding cache item - so that you can expire the token.

When another browser or login occurs and the token is within a certain date then you can either suppress the login attempt or generate a new token which would logout the first browser user.

An example filter is shown below.

```
    public class SignOnCheckerFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public SignOnCheckerFilter (){}

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            bool checkOk = false;
            if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //read cookie or claims
                
                //check match

                //if match success
                checkOk = true;
            }

            //return if checkOk
            if(checkOk) return;
            //return forbidden result if invalid match (you could redirect the user to a logout page?)
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
```